# How to mock constructor injected @Value property in Spring Boot Unit Testing

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I have a service as below with constructor dependency injection of a service and a configuration property.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private OtherService service;

    private final SomeClass c;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(
        OtherService service,
        @Value("${app.some-property}") String someProperty) {

        this.service = service;
        final String key = service.getKey();
        SomeClient client = new SomeClient(key, someProperty);
        c = new SomeClass(client);
    }
}
```

How should we inject/mock value for property ${app.some-property} in unit test case using Mockito?

Comment: You don't. Call the constructor with the value you want, or use `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

What also works is using the 'ReflectionTestUtils' provided by spring to set the values within the mock:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(target, "name", value);
```

in this case target would be the mocked class in your unit test, e.g. annotated by @Mock and the static call above could be done in a function thats executed before all or before each test.

[Spring ReflectionUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can but you should not, because `@Value` is a spring annotation, and to get values assigned into it you should use the Spring provided Test mechanism.

Instead of using `@RunsWith(MockitoRunner.class)` start using `@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)`

And create a test property file in your `src/test/resources` directory with the needed property, and then your test can get that property value assigned automatically